# Check for HTML tags

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to find out if there are any HTML tags, so far I have:

```
/^[^<>]+$/
```

It's for a validator, if no HTML tags exist, it will validate.

Comment: So whats your question now?

Comment: I guess a usual duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-text-that-doesnt-contain-a-word.

Comment: Please could you tell me why its a duplicate.

Comment: Because the answer is there.

Comment: What's wrong with [what you have](https://regex101.com/r/eT4zF2/1)?

Comment: @JamesThorpe it seems to match when there is HTML tags, I need to match when there are NO tags.

Comment: @stribizhev where is the answer?

Comment: @panthro Are you sure?  Check my link?

Comment: @panthro: https://regex101.com/r/qI5cC1/2 - `^((?!<[^<]*>)[\s\S])*$` (the multiline mode is on to check separate lines in the demo)

Comment: @JamesThorpe ive checked your link, it has two matches, i need it to validate when there are 0 matches

Comment: The two matches don't contain any elements...?  @stribizhev version is better as it allows single `<` or `>` to be in the text also, if that's allowed in your case

Comment: @panthro: This is an example without multiline mode on: https://regex101.com/r/qI5cC1/3. Just remove the tags, and you will get a match. But if there are stray `<`s or `>`s, they might ruin this logic. What about your input? Can you have those stray angle brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the adapted version of the regex in this SO post:

```
^((?!<[^<]+>)[\s\S])*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qI5cC1/3).

Perhaps, you can further enhance it to only match if the first character after `<` is a letter:

```
^((?!<[a-zA-Z][^<]*>)[\s\S])*$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/qI5cC1/5)

Comment: What's with `[\s\S]`?  Space or not space?  Is there a benefit to using that over using `.` with the `s` option?

Comment: In JavaScript, there is no `s` option.

Answer (score 0):

You use a regex like this:

```
.*<\/?.*?>.*
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/oD7qY3/1)**

The idea is to find strings with tags like `<tag>`, `<tag withAttribute="something">` or `</closingTag>`

[image]

Update: as [Mr. Llama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477563/mr-llama) pointed in his comment you could enable `s` flag to enable `.` to match all. This will help you with multiple line strings.

```
(?s).*<\/?.*?>.*
 ^--- use this for inline single line flag or use the first regex but enable the `s` flag
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/oD7qY3/2)**

Comment: You should probably also enable the `s` "dot all" option so that it includes newlines.  HTML tags are allowed to span multiple lines.